# Cypress test cases in gitHub actions with local server (localhost:3000), the test cases passed but finally getting timeout error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

[image: error screenshot here]

I have written test cases with cypress in react and want to configure them in the GitHub actions on every single push.

All the test cases were executing properly without any issues when I ran them on the local machine which is port: localhost:3000

**Even in the GitHub actions, the test cases were executing properly after a few seconds am getting the timeout error.**

`Error: http://localhost:3000 timed out on retry 91 of 3, elapsed 90259ms, limit 90000ms Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`

### Here is my .yml configuration for GitHub workflow:

```
name: On Push hook

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
      - '*/*'
      - '**'
      - '!prd'
      - '!tst'
      - '!dev'

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  validate-code:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Use Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
      - name: Use .npmrc
        uses: bduff9/use-npmrc@v1.1
        with:
          dot-npmrc: ${{ secrets.ORG_NPMRC }}
      - name: Build packages
        run: |
          cd src 
          yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - name: Lint
        run: |
          cd src
          yarn lint
      - name: TypeCheck
        run: |
          cd src
          yarn tsc
      - name: Setup yarn package
        run: yarn init -y && yarn install
      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd src
          yarn build
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          install: false
          project: ./src
          working-directory: src
          start: |
            yarn start 
            yarn cy:run
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000'
          wait-on-timeout: 120
        env:
          EMAIL: xxxxxxx
          PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
```

**Test cases were getting executed as expected in gitHub actions but finally producing the timeout error.
Am expecting to move next actions as soon as all test cases passed.**

Comment: Using `start: yarn cy:run` means that you are starting the tests before `wait-on` has completed. You should probably remove `yarn cy:run` because `cypress-io/github-action` automatically starts the tests after `wait-on` has completed.

Comment: This issue was also cross-posted to https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/issues/858.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`
using the `wait-on` parameter of [cypress-io/github-action](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action) is that the server you are using is not responding on IPv4 and is only responding to the IPv6 address `::1`.

[wait-on with Node.js 18+](https://%5Bwait-on%20with%20Node.js%2018+%5D(https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/blob/master/README.md#wait-on-with-nodejs-18)) in the README of the repository describes the workarounds.

The simplest in this case is to replace
`wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000'` by
`wait-on: 'http://[::1]:3000'`

Comment: Yes, that has worked fine. many thanks....

Comment: @anil Please tick the answer as correct, since you say that it worked.